# Executing spark first time takes approximately 13 seconds, but second, and every other time it takes 3.5 seconds

Tags: apache-spark, flask, pyspark

I am using pyspark and Flask for interactive spark as service application.
My application should get some request with some parameters and return response back. My code is here:

```
//first I make udf function
def dict_list(x, y):
        return dict((zip(map(str, x), map(str, y))))

dict_list_udf = F.udf(lambda x, y: dict_list(x, y), 
    types.MapType(types.StringType(), types.StringType()))

//then I read my table from cassandra
        df2 = spark.read \
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
            .options(table="property_change", keyspace="strat_keyspace_cassandra_raw2") \
            .load()

@app.route("/test/<serviceMatch>/<matchPattern>")
def getNodeEntries1(serviceMatch, matchPattern):

    result_df = df2.filter(df2.id.like(matchPattern + "%") & (df2.property_name == serviceMatch)) \
        .groupBy("property_name") \
        .agg(F.collect_list("time").alias('time'), F.collect_list("value").alias('value'))

    return json.dumps(result_df.withColumn('values', dict_list_udf(result_df.time, result_df.value)).select('values').take(1))
```

When I start my server(using spark submit), and use Postman for get request, i takes about 13 seconds first time to give me  response, and after that every other response takes approximately 3 seconds. To serve users with delay of 13 seconds at first is not acceptable. I am new spark user and I am assuming that this behaviour is due to the spark nature, but I do not know what exactly is causing it. Maube something about caching or compiling execution plan like sql queries. Is there any chance that I could solve this problem. Ps I am new user, so sorry if my question is not clear enought or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Such delay is fully expected. Skipping over simple fact that Spark is not designed to be used directly embedded in an interactive application (nor is suitable for real time queries) there is simply a significant overhead of

- Initializing context.
- Acquiring resources from the cluster manager.
- Fetching metadata from Cassandra.

The question is if it makes any sense to use Spark here at all - if you need close to real time response, and you collect full results to the driver, using [native Cassandra connector](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/) should be much better choice.

However if you plan to execute logic that is not supported by Cassandra itself then all you can do is accept the cost of such indirect architecture.

Comment: This is just for testing. The thing is that cassandra's CQL does not support grouping and aggregation, so I am testing different approaches. Thanks for the answer, it was helpful.